# {options:my_field_name} not working

Tags: custom-fields, forms, fields

I have this code in my safecracker form

```
<select class="span2" data-title="Help" data-placement="right" data-trigger="focus" data-content="{instructions:gender}" disabled id="gender">
 {options:gender}
   <option value="{option_value}" {selected}>{option_name}</option>
 {/options:gender}
</select>
```

`genders` is a relationship field. According to the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/#custom-fields), I should be able to generate options for a select field using this syntax

```
<select name="my_field_name">
        {options:my_field_name}
                <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
        {/options:my_field_name}
</select>
```

This doesn't work for me.

However, using

`{field:gender}`

works but outputs a select dropdown. I don't want this since I want to specify some attributes for the select tag as you can see above.

Any idea why this is the case?

I am using EE 2.5.5

Comment: This worked for me: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/12637/1335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this code example:

```
{custom_fields}
    {if relationship AND field_name == 'gender'}
        <select id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}[data][]">
            {options}
                <option value="{option_value}"{selected}>{option_name}</option>
            {/options}
        </select>
    {/if}
{/custom_fields}
```

I hope, it would work for you.

Comment: In my case, I don't think I need `[data][]`. I got an error. So I removed and it worked for me.

Comment: glad to know it.