# Fieldpack 2.1 (P&T) EE2.6.1 and Safecracker Dropdown Not Working

Tags: ee2, safecracker, pixelandtonic, field-pack

I've just upgraded a site to EE2.6 with P&T Fieldpack 2.1

all of my safecracker dropdowns are now giving {option_name} instead of my proper Options. My dropdown template code is using the following

{options:myfieldname}
     {option_name}
{/options:myfieldname}

This code output correctly with EE2.5.5 and P&T Dropdown 1

Can anyone help out with the correct Dropdown syntax or a working solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{options:field_name}` tag pair is actually a Safecracker tag, which only works with Field Pack 1.x out of the box. You can add Field Pack 2.x support by opening up system/expressionengine/config/config.php and adding these lines:

```
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_checkboxes';
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_radio_buttons';
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_dropdown';
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_multiselect';
$config['safecracker_option_fields'][] = 'fieldpack_pill';
```

Comment: What effect would this have if I upgrade to 2.7.2?

Comment: Same; this applies to EE 2.6 and later.